# ARC and re-using pointers exhausts memory

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I thought I had my head around retains and releases until ARC got implemented, I tend to try to reuse pointers to save having to re-declare them all the time.

But with ARC, it creates a leak. My guess is it's only releasing the last object assigned to the 'tmp' pointer, I assumed when I gave a pointer a new object, the old object would automatically be released. Wrapping the function within an autoreleasepool seems to do the job, but is this really the ideal solution or is my coding style wrong?

Here is the guilty function that seems to eat up all my ram after I run it a few hundred times:

```
- (void) saveJDictEntry:(JDictEntry *)entry {

  const char * query;
  char * errMsg;
  NSString *queryString;    
  sqlite3_stmt * statement;

  [self connect];   

  // Insert the word..
  queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO words (seq) VALUES (%i)", entry.number];
  query = [queryString UTF8String];
  if (sqlite3_exec(database, query, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK) {
      NSLog(@"Statement failed %@ %@", errMsg, queryString);
  }


  // Get the last id we inserted..
  NSUInteger lastId = 0;
  queryString = @"SELECT last_insert_rowid()";
  query = [queryString UTF8String];
  sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query, -1, &statement, NULL);    
  if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
      lastId =  sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
  } else {
      NSLog(@"Failed to fetch last Id after saving");        
  }
  sqlite3_finalize(statement);    

  entry.databaseId = lastId;
  entry.saved = true;



  // Kana...
  queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO words_kana (word_id, kana) VALUES (%i, '%@')", entry.databaseId, entry.kana ];
  query = [queryString UTF8String];    
  if (sqlite3_exec(database, query, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK) {
      NSLog(@"Statement failed %@ %@", errMsg, queryString);
  }        

  // Kanji ...
  for(NSString * _kanji in entry.kanji) {
      queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO words_kanji (word_id, kanji) VALUES (%i, '%@')", entry.databaseId, _kanji];
      query = [queryString UTF8String];    
      if (sqlite3_exec(database, query, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK) {
          NSLog(@"Statement failed %@ %@", errMsg, queryString);
      }              
  }

  // Pos..
  for(NSString * _pos in entry.pos) {
      queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO words_pos (word_id, pos) VALUES (%i, '%@')", entry.databaseId, _pos];
      query = [queryString UTF8String];    
      if (sqlite3_exec(database, query, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK) {
          NSLog(@"Statement failed %@ %@", errMsg, queryString);
      }              
  }

  // Gloss
  for(NSString * _gloss in entry.gloss) {
      NSString * glossField = [_gloss stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"''"];            
      queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO words_gloss (word_id, gloss) VALUES (%i, '%@')", entry.databaseId, glossField];
      query = [queryString UTF8String];    
      if (sqlite3_exec(database, query, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK) {
          NSLog(@"Statement failed %@ %@", errMsg, queryString);
      }              
  }   


}
```

Comment: That isn't real code is it? You're allocating statics, there is nothing to leak. Please post real code if you would like to have real answers.

Comment: Does the static analyzer note it is a leak, or the Leaks from Instruments?

Comment: Thanks, I've posted some of the actual code - but unless I'm being thick (quite possible) it's the same concept. I get memory warnings and then force quits unless I wrap it in autoreleasepools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The old memory management concept still holds true that autoreleased instances in global release pool won't be release before finishing current run loop, with or without ARC.

If you are writing non-trivial iteration e.g. thousands iteration, wrapping it with autorelease pool is the way to go. You might use

```
@autoreleasepool {
    // your code here
}
```

for simplifying usage. There's nothing wrong or non-ideal with using autorelease pool, as it's been there for some reason. ARC, as its name suggests, only do automatic reference counting. The task of managing memory usage still belongs to us.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it held on to them until it finished the loop. That function is called inside another loop, which is inside a big importer loop.. so I guess it was holding on to them because of this.

Comment: @RoyalFool - In addition to wrapping with an autorelease pool, you could also try replacing the convenience constructors like `-stringWithFormat:` with methods like `-initWithFormat:` to avoid getting autoreleased instances from those parts of your code. This would reduce the aggregation of autoreleased objects.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your given example. No leaking, absolutely not: neither on iOS5 app, nor desktop app. Also checked in Instruments. (Xcode 4.2.1, Build 4D502, compiled with LLVM 3.0)